# Isabelle : complement of datatype

Tags: isabelle

```
datatype aaa = A | B
lemma "(a ~= A) --> (a = B)"
```

How to prove this basic lemma? I'm relatively new to  Isabelle, and the problem is confusing.

Comment: Another strategy to try as a beginner is to use sledgehammer. For this kind of lemma, it'll definitely quickly come back with a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via case-analysis on a:

```
by (cases a, auto)
```